# How does the indexing of the box in this gltf file work?

Tags: opengl, gltf

So from my understanding if I want to render a box using indexed triangles, I would need 8 vertices (for the 8 corner points) and 36 indices (the box has 6 sides, with  2 triangles per side and 3 indices per triangle, 6*2*3=36).

So consider the gltf file found [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/2.0/Box). It is a correct file and I can see the right amount of vertices and indices. However the indices are:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 10, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 14, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 18, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23, 22, 21]
```

if i read them correctly. I thought these numbers would never rise above 7 (as there are only 8 vertices to index). Did I read the file incorrectly or how does this indexing work?

Comment: "as there are only 8 vertices to index" No, in this model, there are 24, which is also exactly what to expect for a cube with normals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did read the file correctly. Except the cube doesn't have 8 vertices. It has 24. This is the case because, apart from storing position data, they also store [normals](https://learnopengl.com/Lighting/Basic-Lighting). OpenGL allows for single-indexing, that is positions, normals, tangets etc. cannot be indexed separately. This means that some vertices need to be duplicated, to be able to be indexed properly. This is explained well [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-9-vbo-indexing/).

Comment: Thanks, the second link (specifically the section "Shared vs Separate") really helped in combination with the comment from derhass. If anyone comes across the same problem, check those out.